# Will I be able to save game in Minecraft PE on my iPad Mini 2?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering if I can save my village on my iPad mini 2 just like on PC. Does it have the same features as on PC?

Answer (score 1):

***There are numerous differences between Minecraft PC and PE***

If you would like for a comparison, [this site does a great job](http://minemum.com/which-version) of describing the basics changes, [while this site](http://www.supercheats.com/minecraft-pocket-edition/walkthrough/minecraft-pe-version-differences) goes into more depth between the changes, including with the console version. The answer your first question, yes you **can**
 save in Minecraft PE

---

## Sources/Additional Info:

[Which Minecraft Version Should We Get?](http://minemum.com/which-version)

[Minecraft PE Version Differences](http://www.supercheats.com/minecraft-pocket-edition/walkthrough/minecraft-pe-version-differences)

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are playing the paid version on the Ipad Mini 2 then yes it should automatically save for you. Personally if you have a computer and you like Minecraft just buy it on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just click quit to title nothing bad will happen